# static_assert type of a private class member, with no instance

Tags: c++

I would like to statically assert whether a private class member type outside of the class:

```
class Human
{
    public:
        int getInt() const {return myInt;}
    private:
        int myInt{0};
};
```

However, I don't have an instance of the object at the location i'd like to assert.

I tried:

`static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(Human::getInt), int>::value);`

but it requires an instance.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: `static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(((Human*)nullptr)->getInt()), int>::value);` should do nicely? Though probably not the cleanest solution...

Comment: [`std::declval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) lets you pretend you have an instance in non-evaluated contexts like `decltype`.

Comment: you want to assert on the return type of the public getter, right? Or do you really want to assert on the private member?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [std::declval](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) which helps in such cases:

```cpp
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<Human>().getInt()), int>::value);
```